# Is it possible to force GNU libtool to use the Solaris CC compiler instead of GCC?

Tags: solaris, libcurl, libtool

I was curious whether it is possible to force GNU libtool to use the Solaris CC compiler instead of GCC? If so, how might that be done?

Here is libtool build script for libpcre 7.28.1, the SMTP,TCP/IP,etc open source library, which I ran on Solaris UNIX last night.

```
Making all in lib
make[1]: Entering directory `/net/beige/export/marc/DQT/EmailLib/curl-7.28.1/lib'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/net/beige/export/marc/DQT/EmailLib/curl-7.28.1/lib'
if /bin/bash     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../lib     -O2 -Wno-system-headers  -MT libcurl_la-file.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/libcurl_la-file.Tpo" -c -o libcurl_la-file.lo `test -f 'file.c' || echo './'`file.c; \
then mv -f ".deps/libcurl_la-file.Tpo" ".deps/libcurl_la-file.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/libcurl_la-file.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../lib -O2 -Wno-system-headers -MT libcurl_la-file.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcurl_la-file.Tpo -c file.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcurl_la-file.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../lib -O2 -Wno-system-headers -MT libcurl_la-file.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcurl_la-file.Tpo -c file.c -o libcurl_la-file.o >/dev/null 2>&1
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../lib     -O2 -Wno-system-headers  -MT libcurl_la-timeval.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/libcurl_la-timeval.Tpo" -c -o libcurl_la-timeval.lo `test -f 'timeval.c' || echo './'`timeval.c; \
then mv -f ".deps/libcurl_la-timeval.Tpo" ".deps/libcurl_la-timeval.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/libcurl_la-timeval.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../lib -O2 -Wno-system-headers -MT libcurl_la-timeval.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcurl_la-timeval.Tpo -c timeval.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcurl_la-timeval.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../lib -O2 -Wno-system-headers -MT libcurl_la-timeval.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcurl_la-timeval.Tpo -c timeval.c -o libcurl_la-timeval.o >/dev/null 2>&1
```

--------------------------libpcre make CC=cc on Solaris Unix---------------------

```
$ make CC=cc
Making all in lib
make[1]: Entering directory `/net/beige/export/marc/DQT/EmailLib/curl-7.28.1/lib'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/net/beige/export/marc/DQT/EmailLib/curl-7.28.1/lib'
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile cc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../lib     -O2 -Wno-system-headers -MT libcurl_la-file.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/libcurl_la-file.Tpo" -c -o libcurl_la-file.lo `test -f 'file.c' || echo './'`file.c; \
then mv -f ".deps/libcurl_la-file.Tpo" ".deps/libcurl_la-file.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/libcurl_la-file.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
libtool: compile:  cc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../include/curl -I../include -I../include -I../lib -I../lib -O2 -Wno-system-headers -MT libcurl_la-file.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcurl_la-file.Tpo -c file.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libcurl_la-file.o
cc: Warning: option -2 passed to ld
cc: illegal option -Wno-system-headers
make[2]: *** [libcurl_la-file.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/net/beige/export/marc/DQT/EmailLib/curl-7.28.1/lib'

make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/net/beige/export/marc/DQT/EmailLib/curl-7.28.1/lib'

make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't "./configure CC=cc" suffice?

Since gcc and cc will be quite different I think perhaps changing compiler after configure-time might be slightly more error-prone but you can try that as well:

"make CC=cc"

Comment: We just tried make CC=cc on the libpcre-7.28.1 distribution on Solaris Unix and we get compile errors, cc: illegal option -Wno-system-headers shown in the orinal question above which I edited for your potential purview if you have the time today. Thank you for your help, Daniel Stenberg.

Comment: I just tried ./configure CC=cc on the libpcre-7.28.1 distribution on Solaris Unix and we get NO!! compile errors. Thank you for your help, Daniel Stenberg. I will accept your answer in 5 minutes. May I post it on the libpcre-develpers mailing list?

Comment: Sure, please feel free to use this information in any way you please!